# Problems when reading from the computer memory, information previously got from a file

Tags: c++

The problem that I have is that I have writen a code that has to get information from the computer memory. This information has previously got from a ".txt" file and stored in the computer memory in a particular way "simulating a database", but when accessing to the information I have a problem because the code doesn't run in the way I want. Have a look at the code and you will understand what I mean easily.

I enclose a example of ".txt" file that I use and the code I have writen.

Table.txt

```
1|1|30
0|20713TRVl\|8304pCXx|10600UeVt|30935giNrIs|4295D_GvCZM|9311aXuA|30063iTE`G|22658p``PwVJ|18362ZcCE|22644Y]OH|17221UG[]]nX|17084xvEcJVA|3657NP\sg|28737qMZNFm`|895Xupv|16773wASvjpe|5681zqniXpS|10873dwRLmCi|22173KSc`|18129Ekxa|16735rsqT`h|15514pCIB_oE|24295hFk_h|7752\PZX|2233wWOO|29169Y]sFDGx|669[u\M|11533EU]L|25080jaLU
1|19710WM``|11558iiGJg|16155ieHOV|28466QLoVB|18135ygKI|17776VmzB_tj|6481iUwYmN|17666_RDKvt|31467^LIMj|22316YWzc|12797YgoH|6353awg]|27166\FdVg|20077BrEzm|5447qeLC_EH|9193hhQ[l_B|17844WZW`fMe|29811STcAQpO|28993\pLiCh|4987VRSZ]q|12728yCSy]w[|13678ZRPx|5236yMl_|27648Fo_PTXb|6822iznH|13276jQCw|20282daHHmrb|26134eDWqr]u|12310eKt[NZC
2|27807qgNgei|11243Jr_QNtb|24086MzGN]f|9987tugrZj^|9760XEtQVF|28587yY\SH|4842RX`d|3041J]xQgm|24409adRD[U|18525]`nO|24535HyalLG|18439Ilqd|23040tqvfj|8036ROxWCT|25261h[O_|25226eSfjQJ|21524mSJYF|2528[ztVA|31877OznR|27727x_ck_|24510VFKV^xQ|30384MPPOTG|13334nF^xvTM|19217dOsn|2222RQCxC|23913F[vkSsJ|23733uzQQsJc|29996_MMfiRl|10372dYZSwjD
3|31258oSce|7118Vzz\|19941YMRaGx[|18653sMCN|1849klofOhd|14780zuoLZk|19426Ptacg|6885KL^]E|16484Sv]F|29183NEIv|26521aSoDDXU|5456iJqSU|30851qgpz]Tr|22097plFFPFi|12998mL^jt|3993wejdD|8889QUiKc|12706oZd_DXD|3512^EBc]|5691[xXE|14064IfJa|20823jGOxpQ|15712EfWHA|15008cPHve\|15683wrVb|5808IMQcBG|25292xVmOVDp|31242eiTvZF|30793qWgntqf
4|19444dLHkrxk|10456FFb^V|21960sGZfse\|19715xquh|32009RfFmA|28303_QygwKx|28444McTs|5352vQFB|17659uofx|26969QEnBd|22372KVXl|30644KatEOd|8183EsFNBNs|26162P^bxe_E|24586eveWZHE|24907JHRLZdg|6834qctb|11977tOXuXB|12554HUX^F|7215_ZahLAa|3589VjHFc|17681PA]vTqb|16490CBTQ|10866Y^Dno\|26235R]srCEF|13897TVdx`J|27500pcigdWb|11664PYsc|4020HgTsBYq
5|26342wCyV|28887CJ\[fPs|16881^pRVuYY|12388JeriY|2979YQ\w|8099qK\]X|29998]eu_`O|27700NYuL|289bMWVe|4607VpJrmKs|18336koiQ|8611vQrxdYW|6912ttnxpRU|2241CENyF[|29767_mEfEN|14521EiHkHg|22504SBwFbz|29515jYCrme|5754GkzrHAw|14375IiIx|1059QxDB|8136L\gt|18302KScaXq|19659FRYB|16752NHox|23132`izp|23499bgjoprd|30650WVxHkz|1676QqKUJf
6|15294oIFZPM|5488EPgR|24406Mmy^|20820OCMt^q|16097][kmq|29440gR^Lvy|26456OEPdPz|27616[tfnXC|13216IKIYAeG|24027fnDA|17957kiPq|28187ySUmCAf|17381OgaQx|15971vzKkk`|3135UTgf|25648iInf|24565QZA_|9200sp[hi[|18362N`cEpqt|2804rmKJ|11554D[WS|5662O]QK`|13908wbICUok|20744Ixlif|29609STKr|23818Cs`Qp_c|20962dkgnf|8591^ReW\E|28911WtMeO[
7|18239uWQFFF|6201`yH]B|5791]L[v|18435jHkOvT|25511^ySzrH[|18056MjE_JF|14876ipSiEP|29780c`YpTuS|26264pnRADf|12127wIQsq|25181Cdxxq]Z|16977AtaIsv|27087^p^B|1344dnNWLv|9555JOkNp|31734WOOn|18917rCrm\j|28826es_O]f|1811A`mJx|19198naaTi|20803c[StHg]|18017U]jt[z|17751vROZwnS|19350tt]x`G|23177NyJuqd|29149auTX|31230WiRcX|13431uedgr[l|6252Zhkxmed
8|19669Ettu^S|1313RLnFQg|19265jGVvs|9997ZvsCgGB|21710Tsdg\x|32553RgvPH|12229xjWYIe|8512^IWkNSm|28498BXIsolk|2299KxvZ|16969yoUUVR|5934uu`K|22919^ZOjVRW|25677_csd]bx|14661wbz_|10185QrmzV[|13051lk_kx|26726[kipm|14861BPuPR|13763dtsLp|11680zhor|26464ZqZFb[S|27281bnAZx|30023QphlfNq|32382_wnOWR|6505VhoajP|23526hhycvC[|22126tjbx^\|12085FLtac
9|31896e]mX|11280S[Okg|31451JpeC|13201rSPJsr|28026pLxYgW|1228Ma[O|21756IKkYJFn|21814BYyyhIk|32054VN`j|22057VqEm|13823pdQphy|27089S]utdK|28215TUDMDnv|26276D^\OQ|12959rxlK|688ThznW|9471GiWCPT|26023sNyOjm|18837sOBDM_m|19889pbzFYO|30767XxOCoAE|10377F\bLdp|11542uXXfPj|16480w[UA[x|31384M]s]c|14296E[Iv|31259tUFZl|11865Aj_ib|22757wVYILE
```

And here it is my code

```
#include "hybridDDBBHeader.h" // This is a .h with different classes defined by me
// We have a class "HybridDataBase" that contains the attributes vector<Table> pointer
// We have a class "Table" that contains the attributes int id, int type, int columns, and vector<ElementSet> RowsCols
// We have a class "ElementSet" that contains the attributes vector<strings> elements

int main()
{
vector<Table> TablesDescriptor;

    ifstring ifs("C:\\Table\\Table.txt"); 

    int id; 
    int type; // Don't worry about the meaning of this variable
    int columns; // Don't worry about the meaning of this variable
    vector<string> buffer;
    vector<ElementSet> RowsCols;

    string temp; // Variable where the first row will be stored

    getline( ifs, temp ); // We get ONLY the FIRST LINE of my ".txt" file and we work with it. We take it from my file ifs and we store this first line in string temp

    size_t tokenPos = temp.find("|"); // When we find the simbol "|" we will identify different elements
    int i=0;

    while (tokenPos != string::npos)
    {    
        tokenPos = temp.find("|");   
        if(i==0)
        {
            id = atoi(temp.substr(0, tokenPos).c_str()); 
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            type = atoi(temp.substr(0, tokenPos).c_str()); 
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            columns = atoi(temp.substr(0, tokenPos).c_str()); 
        }
        temp.erase(0, tokenPos+1);
        i=++i;
    }

    // We continue reading the NEXT LINES of our code UNTIL THE END of the file
    while(getline( ifs, temp )) 
    {
    size_t tokenPosition = temp.find("|"); // When we find the simbol "|" we will identify different elements

        while (tokenPosition != string::npos)
        {    
            string element;
            tokenPosition = temp.find("|");      

            element = temp.substr(0, tokenPosition);

            buffer.push_back(element);

            temp.erase(0, tokenPosition+1);
        }

        ElementSet ss(0,buffer);
        RowsCols.push_back(ss); 
    }

    Table TablesStorage (id, type, columns, RowsCols); // After every loop we will store the information about every .txt file in the vector<Table> TablesDescriptor
    TablesDescriptor.push_back(TablesStorage);  // In the vector<Table> TablesDescriptor will be stores all the different tables with all its information
}

HybridDataBase hybriddatabase(1, TablesDescriptor);


cout<<"--- SOLUTION ---"<<endl;
ElementSet selectedElementSet;
Table selectedTable = hybriddatabase.getPointer().at(0); // This works perfectly
selectedTable.setType(1); // This works perfectly, but don't worry about this
selectedElementSet=selectedTable.getRowsCols().at(3);  // PROBLEEEEEEM!!!!!!!!!!!! It doesn't read information from row 3, always row 0

cout<<"selectedElementSet: "<<selectedElementSet.getElements().at(0)<<endl; // This works perfectly
```

I will be waiting for your help. Thank you very much in advance!!! :)

Comment: Without having looked at your code in detail, I think it's necessary that you specify the problem to get any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `ElementSet ss(0,buffer);` you probably want to do `buffer.clear();`

Also, this is pointless: `i=++i;`. Use `++i;`